# sum of maximum and minimum value of $\frac{1}{1+\left(2\cos x-4\sin x\right)^2}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, trigonometry

What is sum of maximum and minimum value of $\frac{1}{1+\left(2\cos x-4\sin x\right)^2} $ over $x \in \mathbb{R}$?

for fraction to be maximum demoninator has to be minimum, that is $(2\cos x-4\sin x)^2$ has to be minimum OR abolute value of $(2\cos x-4\sin x)$ is minimum.

if $2\cos x-4\sin x=0 \implies \tan x=\frac{1}{2}$  so there does exist values of x such that $2\cos x-4\sin x=0$ so maximum value of $\frac{1}{1+\left(2\cos x-4\sin x\right)^2} $ is $1$

how to find minimum of this function.

Comment: Take derivative of $(2\cos x-4\sin x)^2$. You'll find 2 conditions.

Comment: $(\cos x, \sin x) $   is a unit vector in the plane.  The expression $2 \cos x - 4 \sin x$  is the ordinary dot product of the unit vector with $(2,-4)$    Extremes of the dot product occur when either the two vectors are perpendicular  or they are parallel. What could be a unit vector parallel to $(2,-4)   \; \; ? \; \; \;  $

Answer (score 6, accepted):

\begin{align}
2\cos(x) - 4\sin(x) &= R\cos(\alpha + x) \\
\implies 2\cos(x) - 4\sin(x)& = R\cos(\alpha)\cos(x) - R\sin(\alpha)\sin(x)
\end{align}

Equating coefficients, we have
$$R\cos(\alpha) = 2 \; \text{and} \; R\sin(\alpha) = 4$$

It follows that
$$R^2 = 2^2 + 4^2 \implies R = \pm 2\sqrt{5}$$

Hence,
$$\frac{1}{1+\left(2\cos x-4\sin x\right)^2} = \frac{1}{1 + 20\cos^2(\alpha + x)}$$

Recall that $0 \le \cos^2(x) \le 1$.

Therefore,
$$\max\left(\frac{1}{1+\left(2\cos x-4\sin x\right)^2}\right) = \frac{1}{1 + 20\cdot0} = 1 \tag{1}$$
$$\min\left(\frac{1}{1+\left(2\cos x-4\sin x\right)^2}\right) = \frac{1}{1 + 20\cdot1} = \frac{1}{21} \tag{2}$$

$$(1) + (2) = 1 + \frac{1}{21} = \boxed{\frac{22}{21}}$$